# Set CMD Prompt to always be the current directory name in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, prompt, working-directory

I would like my command prompt to display just the directory name I am currently in, not the full path. If I am working in `C:\Mystuff\Junk\` I would like the command prompt to display:

```
Junk>
```

If I then enter `cd..`, I want the command prompt to display:

```
Mystuff>
```

If I then enter `cd .\Junk\Bla`, I want the command prompt to display:

```
Bla>
```

Is this possible in Windows XP? I've searched for an answer, but I can't find anything that satisfies the query. There was a question similar to this, but no answer was provided.

Comment: It's not possible in `cmd` shell. See [prompt](http://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html) for the only possibilities.

Comment: @DavidPostill That doesn't actually answer the question, only provides a link to the prompt options, which do not seem to allow what I was hoping to accomplish, as you noted in your second comment. Too bad, I guess set prompt=$p$_$_$g will have to do.

Comment: That is probably why he didn't actually post it as an answer.

Comment: @EBGreen, What I meant by "That doesn't answer the question", was that the linked question in his first comment does not answer my question, not his comments themselves not answering it. Although, his second comment does answer the question, and should probably have been an answer instead of a comment. Also, was this conjecture really necessary? It's not adding anything to the question or answer.

Comment: My point is that ***comments** are not expected to be an ***answer**

Comment: "the linked question in his first comment does not answer my question," It's still the same question (whether the answers satisfy you or not), and therefore a duplicate.  If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question, please earn a bit more Rep and place a [Bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it.